# How to save user selection over a FriendPicker in Android with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use a facebook friend picker as a UI for integrate a blacklist in my app.
What I want to do is show user's friends which use my app and allow the user to select some of them and put them in a blacklist.
I have no problem with that but how can I re-show the previous user selection when he comes back to this picker a second time?

I've tried the way suggested by il4.serg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541945/mark-selected-user-as-checked-in-friendpicker-facebook-sdk-for-android) and using a json to get the friends blocked, but when I try to add another friend, in the setOnSelectionChangedListener I only get data from the already selected users, and if I touch a selected friend the activity crashes....

Comment: Currently not possible with the existing APIs.

Comment: I see, thank you! I've courrently change my approach to the problem and solved creating a listview from a json file.